# unable to import parallel modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.10

I did some research and tried to apply it but failed.
I have a project structured like so using python 3.10:

```
└── project
    ├── main
    │   └── main.py
    └── pkg1
        └── module.py
```

module.py and main.py are nothing fancy:

```py
#module1.py
def hello():
    print('hello')
```

yet in main.py all imports fail (obviously i call only one of the 3).

```py
#main.py
from pkg1.module import hello
from .pkg1.module import hello
from ..pkg1.module import hello

hello()
```

For any of the tried imports I get:

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

How do I import the module?
And yes, I have to keep the file/folder structure as is because of constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the `main` module via the [`-m` switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) from the parent directory of `project` and then use `from ..pkg1.module import hello`. This way the `..` can be resolved as there is a parent package (namely `project`):

```
python -m project.main.main
```

An alternative is to extend [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) and add the `project` directory to the search path in `main.py`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/project')

from pgk1.module import hello
```

Then you can invoked the main script from within the `main` directory using `python main.py`.

If you are invoking it from within `project`, via `python main/main.py`, then you don't even need the path modification as the current working directory will be added to the search path automatically.

Comment: appending to the path was perfect. I know it might not be the best thing but this allows me to have multiple different mains using the same packages (I know, maybe I should "wheel them up")

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a parent package and you put your entrypoint **main**.py at the root of that package.

```
project ( your actual project root)
    |_project/ (your package root)
        |_ __init__.py (empty)
        |_ __main__.py (contents: from pkg1.module import hello; hello())
        |_ pkg1/
            |_ __init__.py (empty)
            |_ module.py (content: def hello: ...)
```

Edit:

From that structure, if you have a scenario where a package must use a sibling package, you will have solve the parent package problem

for example, import pkg2 from pkg1. No problem if you run from top level module.

```
project
    |_project/
        |_ __init__.py
        |_ __main__.py (contents: from pkg1.module import hello; hello())
        |_ pkg1/
            |_ __init__.py
            |_ module.py (content:from pkg2.module import hi; def hello: hi())
        |_ pkg2/
            |_ __init__.py
            |_ module.py (content: def hi: ...)
```

Comment: indeed it works, yet it defeats a bit the purpose: I need to keep the structure of the folders unfortunately

Comment: @Wing I edit a liitle my answer with a sibling module importation scenario.

Comment: You can't import a module from a sibling one you are not doing it from a parent package (declared with `__init__.py`)  that knows both modules. In the case shown in your question, there is no way that main can know about pkg1.

Comment: @Peterrabit: Thanks! I am still getting to know python (I come from C++). I'll try to get around it somehow then